# How to see which files a Makefile uses?

Tags: linux, kernel, make, c

I have the following makefile which is supposed to build procdriver.c and thus output a .ko file. The issue is that even when I delete procdriver.c my makefile seems to be able to build a procdriver.ko file. I would like to try to find out from where it gets the source file it is building every time.

```
TARGET = procdriver

obj-m := procdriver.o 
procdriver-objs+= gpioLib.o

KDIR:= /home/pi/myRpi/linux
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all: gpioLib.o procdriver.c
    echo<<"in all"
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules 
    rm -r -f .tmp_versions *.mod.c .*.cmd *.o *.symvers 



gpioLib.o: gpioLib.c gpioLib.h 
    gcc -c gpioLib.c -o gpioLib.o

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

This is the output from the Makefile: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23575533/

Comment: The `-d` (debug) option shows what you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

The **`-d`** (debug) option shows what you need to know, e.g.,

```
make -d |less
```

since the output appears to go to the standard output.  Once in `less`, you can search up/down for the interesting details.

You *could* use `grep`, but will lose *context*:

```
make -d | grep whatever
```

In some cases, it helps to see what possibilities `make` has already considered (and what *rules* it has loaded) to make sense of the output.

For instance, when you trace it, you'll see the effect of this line:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

which runs *another* make in the `$(KDIR)` directory.  That's where the `procdriver` module is created:

```
  Must remake target '/home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.o'.
set -e;  echo '  LD [M]  /home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.o'; ld -EL    -r -o /home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.o /home/pi/myRpi/gpioLib.o ; printf '%s\n' 'cmd_/home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.o := ld -EL    -r -o /home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.o /home/pi/myRpi/gpioLib.o ' > /home/pi/myRpi/.procdriver.o.cmd
{ echo /home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.ko; echo /home/pi/myRpi/gpioLib.o; } > /home/pi/myRpi/.tmp_versions/procdriver.mod
  Successfully remade target file '/home/pi/myRpi/procdriver.o'.
```

The example on the pastebin starts in the middle of the trace.  When I looked at a quick example, the previous section ends with this:

```
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.procdriver.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `procdriver'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `procdriver.w'.
   No implicit rule found for `procdriver.c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `procdriver.c'.
  No need to remake target `procdriver.c'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
```

Either you have a `procdriver.c` in your directory, or (study the trace) some other feature helps the `make` program find that it was not necessary.  In either case, it doesn't use that file in the trace for the sub-make.

By the way, that debug-option is not in [POSIX make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), though you are unlikely to encounter a version of `make` without the feature.  For instance, [SunOS 4](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%204.1.3&arch=default&format=html) did that, and [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/make-1s.html#scrolltoc) continues to provide it.

Comment: Is it possible to add the "grep" command to only output the lines containing a specific word?

Comment: Unfortunately the -d flag didn't give an output containing procdriver.c so I still don't know from where it gets procdriver.c ... Any suggestions?

Comment: I upvoted your answer but didn't accept it, as it only answers to a part of a question.

Comment: this is the output from the Makefile: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23575533/